# Uri type file:// to Uri type Content://

Tags: android, uri, android-camera, android-image

I want to crop an image that I got the absolute path

If I try to put an uri of type "file://" It doesnt work, I need a "Content://" uri but I dont know how to transform it.

Example of file:// uri :

```
file:///storage/sdcard0/tmp_contact_1375908866280.jpg
```

Example of Content:// uri that i need:

```
content://media/external/images/media/492
```

My code to crop

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setData(ur);
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 500);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 500);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, IMAGEN_FINAL_SUBIR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way would be to insert the image into the media manager and use the uri returned from that..

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html

.. take a look at the insertImage.. it returns a content uri string to the inserted image